# Is it possible to set the value of `this` inside a promise executor function?

Tags: javascript, this, es6-promise

Is it possible in this code:

```
var this_module = {

    foo: 'something'

    promise: new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {

        resolve (this.foo);
        })
}
```

to set the value of `this` to be `this_module` so that `this.foo` will be `foo: 'something'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax:

```
var this_module = {

    foo: 'something'

    get promise() {
       return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
          resolve (this.foo);
       }.bind(this))
    }
}
```

It happens because you don't have the object itself initialized when adding the property to it `promise: new Promise()`.
In a getter, the object is initialized already and the callback can be bind with `this` object ([see more](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#6boundfunction) about `.bind()`).

Note: This will return a new promise every time the property is accessed (thanks @Felix).

Comment: Note that this will return a new promise every time the property is accessed.

Comment: @FelixKling It's easy to store the promise in an internal property, if it's necessary.

Comment: Right, but it's still important to note that :)

Comment: Thank you @DmitriPavlutin! I discovered that I actually need the property to return a new promise each time it is accessed - and for that your `getter` was the right solution. As I bonus I also found out that a lazy `getter` was a perfect solution for another problem I was struggling with. So all in all I have check marked this answer for being the most helpful to me personally even though the solution presented by Felix Kling also solved the problem - in a more simple way and with a cleaner syntax.

Comment: @rabbitco You're welcome. In many cases generating each time a new promise is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Not without calling `new Promise` **after** the object was created:

```
this_module.promise = new Promise(function(...) { ... }.bind(this_module));
```

This is basically the same issue as covered in [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/218196) : you are trying to access the object instance during initialization, which is simply not possible.

Comment: Thank you very much @Felix Kling. I received two solutions which I both find to be very helpful. So I would prefer to check mark both. Unfortunately this is technically not possible. I have given your answer an up vote in a try to "reward" both answers - unsure if that breaks some kind of Stackoverflow protocol. One disadvantage with your otherwise simpler and cleaner solution: In a module with a lot of properties there is a lot of  "lines" between stating the property and setting its value. For more details on my choice see comment to the other answer.